# how to get the copy of object which is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs

Hello every one i am currently working with html5 and easelJS.I have a canvas and an images on it.What I want is that when I click on the image its copy is created and and when I click on some other place at canvas my images is copied there so leaving two images on my canvas.
I want to ask is there a way by which I can know that whether I am clicking on the image or or on the canvas.and How to make a copy of my image as I have wrote some code but it removes my orignal image and place it to ther place leaving only one image on the canvas

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by storing the image that your bitmaps are built from, then re-adding them when you need to paste. Also you'll need to override Stage.prototype._handleMouseDown like this:

```
   window.Stage.prototype._handleMouseDown = function(e){
        if (this.onMouseDown) {
            this.onMouseDown(new MouseEvent("onMouseDown", this.mouseX, this.mouseY, this, e));
        }
        var target = this._getObjectsUnderPoint(this.mouseX, this.mouseY, null, (this._mouseOverIntervalID ? 3 : 1));
        if (target) {
            if (target.onPress instanceof Function) {
                var evt = new MouseEvent("onPress", this.mouseX, this.mouseY, target, e);
                target.onPress(evt);
                if (evt.onMouseMove || evt.onMouseUp) { this._activeMouseEvent = evt; }
            }
            this._activeMouseTarget = target;
        } else {
            this.onPressThrough && this.onPressThrough(e);
        }
    }
```

Then in your implementation define onPressThrough like this.

```
    stage.onPressThrough = function(event){
        console.log("paste");
        paste(event.x, event.y);
    }
```

Here is a complete working example:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

        $(canvas).attr('width', '1000');
        $(canvas).attr('height', '1000');

        $('body').append(canvas);

        var stage = window.stage = new Stage(canvas);
        canvas.stage = stage;


        function copy(target){
            window.clipboard = target;
        }

        function addImage(image, x, y){
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
            bitmap.image = image;

            bitmap.onPress = function(event){
                console.log("copy")
                copy(this.image);
            }
            stage.addChild(bitmap);
            bitmap.x = x || 0;
            bitmap.y = y || 0;

        }

        function paste(x, y){
            window.clipboard && addImage(clipboard, x, y);
        }

        window.Stage.prototype._handleMouseDown = function(e){
            if (this.onMouseDown) {
                this.onMouseDown(new MouseEvent("onMouseDown", this.mouseX, this.mouseY, this, e));
            }
            var target = this._getObjectsUnderPoint(this.mouseX, this.mouseY, null, (this._mouseOverIntervalID ? 3 : 1));
            if (target) {
                if (target.onPress instanceof Function) {
                    var evt = new MouseEvent("onPress", this.mouseX, this.mouseY, target, e);
                    target.onPress(evt);
                    if (evt.onMouseMove || evt.onMouseUp) { this._activeMouseEvent = evt; }
                }
                this._activeMouseTarget = target;
            } else {
                this.onPressThrough && this.onPressThrough(e);
            }
        }

        stage.onPressThrough = function(event){
            console.log("paste");
            paste(event.x, event.y);
        }

        var image = new Image();
        image.src = "assets/images/tempimage.png";
        addImage(image);

        window.tick = function(){
            stage.update();
        }

        Ticker.addListener(window);
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks alot for your help.But can you tell me will I be able to again interact with the image or bitmap like moving it around? hmmm I want to keep track of all the copied images How can I keep track of it.

Comment: add them to an array as you create them. inside of addImage();